# path to resources directory in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, resources, itext7

I need the path to my resources directory to access my fonts folder inside it like the one in this code:

```java
PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.createFont(
    "src/main/resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf", "CP1251", true);
```

but in Xamarin.android. I tried the following:

```java
string uri = "android.resource://" + this.PackageName + "/font/ARIAL.TTF";
PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(
     uri, "CP1251", true);
```

but it doesn't work. I tried this code too:

```
  var path2 = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
            filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2.ToString(), "myfile4.pdf");
            stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
            PdfDocument pdf2 = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document2 = new Document(pdf2, PageSize.A4);
            AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
            string content;
            Stream stream2 = assets.Open("ARIAL.TTF");
            var memorystrm = new MemoryStream();
            stream2.CopyTo(memorystrm);
            byte[] t = memorystrm.ToArray();
            Toast.MakeText(this, t.Length.ToString(), ToastLength.Long);
            if (t != null)
            {
                PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(t, "UTF-8", true);
                document2.SetFont(russian);
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello World! ")
                    .Add(new Text("صباح! ").SetFontSize(14)).Add(new Text("Bonjour le monde! ").SetFontSize(10));
                document2.Add(p);
                document2.Close();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "done", ToastLength.Long);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "error", ToastLength.Long);
            }
```

no code was exceuted

Comment: The path of the folder of the Xamarin.Android project is different with the native Android project. If you want to save the font file in the project to access the file, try to save the files in the Asset folder.Set the Build Action for this files to AndroidAsset. Check the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: If you've solved the issue, please accept the solution as the answer. It'll help others who face the simiar problem

Comment: thanks a lot sir. just one thing, after reading the font as bytes and including the font for the pdf document, the latter was supposed to read Arabic words. but it didn't, could it be a problem with the bytes?

Comment: From search, 'Paragraph' seems doesn't support the Arabic text. For this function, try to use the 'PdfCalligraph' library to do the work. 'PdfCalligraph' is provided by the iText 7 support and it aims to support many more languages and writing systems.

Comment: yes sir, i'm using 'PdfCalligraph'. I've referred to this link https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/displaying-text-different-languages-single-pdf-document to write my code and from it I started getting the problems of how to read my font and where to put it, but still my pdf didn't read arabic

Comment: Did you save the text as a separate XML file such as arabic.xml? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text direction="rtl">هذه هي الجملة المستخدمة في المثال.</text>` Then get the text using the following command:`XmlNode element = doc.GetElementsByTagName("text").Item(0);
...
paragraph.Add(element.InnerText);
document.Add(paragraph);`

Comment: no, I thought this was just an example and the main point is to specify a font for the pdf. is this a main step? cause my real data are found in a database with hundreds of rows and many columns, so how will put all those data in an xml file to put them in a table in a pdf file?

Comment: Try using the xml files to test if the code will work first. To use pdfCalligraph you simply load the correct binaries into your project, make sure your valid license file is loaded.

Comment: okay sir, i will try it as you said. I downloaded the pdfcalligraph using Nuget manager as an ad-on for itext7, is this a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

The path of the folder of the Xamarin.Android project is different with the native Android project.

If you want to save the font file in the project to access the file, try to save the files in the **Asset** folder.Set the **Build Action** for this files to **AndroidAsset**.

```
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Check the tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

## Update

> i'll add my code, it didn't work. no code was executed

It seems that you forgot to add the `.Show()` code such as `Toast.MakeText(this, "done", ToastLength.Long).Show()`.

Comment: yes I've tried something like this, i'll add my code, it didn't work. no code was executed

Comment: Do you mean that the 'Toast' is not display? It seems that you forgot to add the `.Show()` code such as `Toast.MakeText(this, "done", ToastLength.Long).Show();`.

Comment: @rana hd If you've solved the issue, please accept the solution as the answer. It will be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.